# Find Query Monogodb take too long

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have collections with document count of around 550,000,000 (documents/rows/records).
It is taking too long to find.
The collection doc has only one field and id.
I need to search if return the docs containing fields.

Below is a sample document from the collection

```
{ _id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,    
'Service Area Code': 15,
Phone: 89898989898898,
Preferences: 0,
Opstype: 'X',
'Phone Type': 0 }
```

and this is a sample query

```
db.collection('xxxx').find({Phone:[898989898989,898989897777,78787878787]})
```

And this is collections is just an initial dump.
It will be getting estimated 0.5 to 1 million records per week.

I am currently using mongodb npm package with node js to do this.

The current time to query is around 5 to 6 mins.

Comment: can you create an index on Phone column and see if it boosts up the query time

Comment: "The collection doc has only one field and id" this contradicts with the sample document. What exactly is is `[....]`? Did you set appropriate indexes?

Comment: start with creating an index over the field

Comment: I am trying this option. but adding index is taking bit of time. let me update u in a bit

Comment: adding the index is throwing out of memory.

Comment: Make sure your indexes fit in memory https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Answer (score 0):

If this query `db.collection('xxxx').find({Phone:[xxxxxx]})` is used frequently, you should [create index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) on the Phone field to speed up your query